# questions for old 3 wire feed to detached garage subpanel with disconnect added

Tags: electrical-panel, garage

i am looking for confirmation than an older garage subpanel feed was correctly wired to meet an older code and is not unsafe.

there is a 3 wire feeder from the house service in underground pvc conduit. it has two hots and a neutral.  there is no sheathing and no ground wire to the house but there is a ground rod at garage.  no other metal connection from garage to the house.

the feed goes to a 60 amp non-fused disconnect outside the garage.  the hots are run through the disconnect to a teck 90 4 wire that continues to a 60 amp subpanel inside the garage.  the neutral feed is  wire nutted to the teck90 neutral inside the disconnect.

the ground rod at the garage is bonded to the disconnect box ground bus bar and so is the teck cable ground wire.

at the subpanel the hots go through the 60 amp breaker.  both the neutral and the ground wire from the teck cable are bonded directly to the ground bus bar.

the panel and garage wiring including gfci outlets test correct and show no faults.

the feed and subpanel is quite old.  the disconnect and teck cable looks to be last 20 years.  the house was a long time rental so not much history.

if this is all wired right to meet some past code, can i or should i change anything to improve safety or meet code short of running a new 4 wire which would be hard with what is in between these two buildings?  would like to update the subpanel.

Comment: Usually new code is changed because there is a safety issue with the older code.  One example is the old hot,hot neutral circuits for dryers/stoves.  Putting in new circuits of that type were banned in 96, but you can still use an old circuit without changing it to new code if you like to gamble.  You have it in conduit, so much easier to add a ground than if it was direct buried cable.

Comment: By the mention of "Teck" cable can we presume you're up in the Frozen North of Canada?

Comment: Also, how big is that PVC conduit, and is it a continuous run between the buildings?

Comment: yes in canada.  the conduit is 1" and is not pvc.  on closer inspection it is similar to soft bendy poly irrigation line.  distance is 150'.  i was told i need to replace it with armoured cable if i go that route and could not fish new wires inside conduit.  there are  paved areas between house and garage so that will be not fun.

Comment: Didn't you say there's conduit between the buildings?  Or is it just a stub-up?  They do make flex conduit legal for burial. The old wires may be grandfathered, in which just pull in a ground. Pavement has a favorable effect on allowed burial depth.